# Mi Iterador no substituye dentro de un arreglo de cadenas

Tags: java, iteradores

En un servlet estoy recogiendo unos parametros de un jsp de esta manera

```
//Parametro urls

String urls[] = request.getParameterValues("urls");

//Parametro busca

String busca[] = request.getParameterValues("busca");
```

y posteriormente los paso a una clase java

```
if (op.equals("EOH")){
    try{
        request.setAttribute("CUEST_P",EOH_ctl.EOH_Prov.CUEST(urls));
        request.setAttribute("DIR_P",EOH_ctl.EOH_Prov.DIR(urls,busca,reemplaza));
        request.setAttribute("DIR_XML_P",EOH_ctl.EOH_Prov.DIR_XML(urls));
        request.setAttribute("HAB_XML_P",EOH_ctl.EOH_Prov.HAB_XML(urls)); 
        request.setAttribute("PERSONAL_P",EOH_ctl.EOH_Prov.PERSONAL(urls));

        request.setAttribute("VIA_P", EOH_ctl.EOH_Prov.VIA(urls));
        request.setAttribute("VIA_XML_P",EOH_ctl.EOH_Prov.VIA_XML(urls));
        request.setAttribute("CUEST_D",EOH_ctl.EOH_Def.CUEST(urls)); 
        request.setAttribute("DIR_D",EOH_ctl.EOH_Def.DIR(urls,busca,reemplaza));
        request.setAttribute("DIR_XML_D",EOH_ctl.EOH_Def.DIR_XML(urls));  
        request.setAttribute("HAB_XML_D",EOH_ctl.EOH_Def.HAB_XML(urls));  
        request.setAttribute("PERSONAL_D",EOH_ctl.EOH_Def.PERSONAL(urls));

        request.setAttribute("VIA_D", EOH_ctl.EOH_Def.VIA(urls));        
        request.setAttribute("VIA_XML_D",EOH_ctl.EOH_Def.VIA_XML(urls));  
        request.getRequestDispatcher("CargaEOH.jsp").forward(request, response );
    } catch (Exception ex){
        request.setAttribute("error", ex.getMessage());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("CargaEOH.jsp").forward(request, response );
    }
}
```

Dentro de la clase donde lo paso, se lo paso a otra clase diferente de esta manera

```
//Buscamos y reemplazamos

FindAndReplace_txt.Reemplazar(objeto,busca,reemplaza);
```

Ahora cuando ya se lo he pasado estoy intentando hacer un iterador, pero no me esta funcionando

```
public static void Reemplazar(Objeto_Ditto objeto, String busca[], String reemplaza[]){

        Iterator<String> it = busca.iterator;

        modifyFile("file", "\\.", "0");

        System.out.println("done");
    }
```

No se por que no me deja crear este iterador para sustituir el \. y el 0

Esta es la clase donde voy a iterar

```
static void modifyFile(String filePath, String oldString, String newString){

    File fileToBeModified = new File(filePath);
    String oldContent = "";
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    FileWriter writer = null;

    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToBeModified)); 
        //Lectura de todas las líneas del archivo
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) 
        {
            oldContent = oldContent + line + System.lineSeparator();
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        //Reemplazo el contenido viejo
        String newContent = oldContent.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
        //Reescrivo el fichero
        writer = new FileWriter(fileToBeModified);
        writer.write(newContent);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            //Closing the resources
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void Reemplazar(Objeto_Ditto objeto, String busca[], String reemplaza[]){
    Iterator<String> it = java.util.Arrays.asList(busca).iterator();
    Iterator<String> it2 = java.util.Arrays.asList(reemplaza).iterator();
    whylie(it.hasnext && it2.hasnext){
        String buscar = it.next();
        String reemplazar = it2.next();
        modifyFile("file", buscar, reemplazar);
    }
}
```

No se si he sido suficientemente especifico, gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Creas un iterador... pero luego no iteras nada. ¿Qué quieres hacer?

Comment: @PabloLozano quiero hacer una iteracion para sustituir donde pone \\. por el resultado de busca y donde pone 0 por el resultado de reemplaza, pero no consigo usar los 2 iterator a la vez, no se si me explico.

Comment: Mi pregunta va a más alto nivel, porque quizá no necesites esos iteradores: Tienes dos arrays de strings, ¿quieres cambiar en un fichero cada ocurrencia de `busca[i]` por `reemplaza[i]`?

Comment: @PabloLozano tengo dos arrays de string, ya que en el mismo fichero tengo que hacer varios reemplazos diferentes, voy a actualizarte el post con lo que he modificado.

Answer (score 0):

No se entiende muy bien cómo quieres usar el iterador. En todo caso el problema es que `busca` es un `String[]` y los arrays sencillamente no tienen una propiedad `iterator`.

Si quieres obtener un iterador, lo más sencillo es crear un `List` con los elementos del array e iterar sobre esta lista.

```
Iterator<String> it = java.util.Arrays.asList(busca).iterator();
```

Comment: El iterador lo voy a utilizar para reemplazar donde pone \\. por busca y donde pone 0 por reemplaza. Es para una clase que hace un find and replace y necesito el iterador, por que es posible que tengas que buscar y reemplazar mas de una cosa a la vez. He añadido la clase completa.